# how to mute barcode2 scan in C#

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

i'm using `Symbol.Barcode2` to scan a picture on MC67 and there is a loud beep when i activate the barcode and when i scan. can these sounds can be muted and how?
i've tried using the `.Config.Scanner.StartBeepTime/ActivityBeepTime/etc`. and nothing.
i've tried to use `.Config.Scanner.ActivityWaveFile/StartWaveFile/etc`. to an empty file and still nothing.
help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to call

```
Barcode2.Config.Scanner.Set();
```

After you set the variables.
It is possible you need to set DecodeBeepTime to 0 also.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i was beginning to think i won't get an answer to the question. unfortunately, this help did not worked... i always use 'Barcode2.Config.Scanner.Set();', and i added the set of DecodeBeepTime to 0, but still got a bip sound when scanning